# Retrieve data from MySQL skipping first 4 ouputs where it's ORDER by id

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize if the title is confusing, it's hard to title this question.

I've been wondering how I could retrieve data from MySQL but only retrieve data skipping first 4 outputs where it's ordered by id.

Ex:

```
function firstFour()
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE category = 'Sports'
    ORDER BY id LIMIT 4");
    $sth->execute();

    $row = $sth->fetch();
    return $row;
}
```

then on the second query, skip the first four where it's ordered by id on the firstFour query above and output the rest of the data from the sports category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put limit like follows
LIMIT 4 , 4

### LIMIT 8 , 4

---

so on

Answer (score 3):

Use this query, your limit 4 is making it start from row 0 and retrieve up to row 4, setting the limit as 4, xxxx will go from 4 to whatever xxxx is. I used a large number in place of xxxx

```
"SELECT data FROM table WHERE category = 'Sports'
 ORDER BY id LIMIT 4, 99999999999"
```

Comment: fixed, I read through it again and realized it wouldn't work. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Zahidul's answer and to make your life easier, you might want to generalize your function a little bit - using `firstFour()`, `secondFour()`, etc. is going to make your life a lot harder.  I would advise taking Zahidul's idea and passing in your limit variable:

```
function anyFour($lowLimit)
{
    $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE category = 'Sports'
    ORDER BY id LIMIT $lowLimit, 4");
    $sth->execute();

    $row = $sth->fetch();
    return $row;
}
```

Then if you wanted to keep the function `firstFour()`, it would be:

```
function firstFour()
{
    return anyFour(0);
}
```

From there, you could create a simple loop that incremented by 4.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < 999;$x++) // 999 should be the total number of sets you want to return...
{
    // on each loop, $myRows returns the next 4 rows:
    $lowLimit = $x * 4;
    $myRows = anyFour($lowLimit);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT data FROM table WHERE category = 'Sports'
ORDER BY id;");
$sth->execute();

$row = $sth->fetch();
$row_num = 0;
while ($row) {
    $row_num +=1;
    if ($row_num > 4) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: $row_num will never reach >4 because the query limits return to 4 rows.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.  I meant to take it out, but forgot to.